# PHP Overwrite Cookie Issue

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

Here's my issue.

I have a site where my users have a page setup for them that displays their information (basically a public profile page) Ex. example.com/johnsmith, example.com/janesmith

When you visit example.com/johnsmith, I used PHP to create a cookie that stores some of John Smiths information, so that when pages outside of John Smith's are being viewed his information will persist across the entire website (example in a banner at the top of the website), so that users can quickly navigate back to John's page.

However, if someone visits example.com/johnsmith and then goes to example.com/janesmith and then clicks back to say the home page, John's information will still display despite the cookie being overwritten with Jane's information until you manually refresh the home page, at which point Jane's information displays correctly.

Any ideas as to what the issue could be causing the overwritten cookie to not display information on other pages until a manual refresh is performed

Comment: By "click back", do you mean just clicking the browsers Back button?

Comment: Hey @EricS thanks for the response. I should have further clarified. I mean if the user clicks one of the main navigation buttons, like "Home" or "About", when it redirects to that page the cookie displays the data prior to it being overwritten then if you manually refresh the page the overwritten cookie with the updated data displays fine.

Comment: by using the "back button", you're likely just viewing the cached version

Comment: @BradKent that was my assumption but I'm not sure how to overcome that particular problem – if it is in fact a caching issue.